# Как создать прототип генератора батчей

Tags: python

- Создайте список длины n
- C помощью циклов и функции random.sample поделите список на непересекающиеся батчи длины m
- Заверните код в генератор (ключевое слово yield)
- Продемонстрируйте правильность работы кода на произвольном списке

Код нерабочий - я решила делать списки (части) в списке. Идея такая, Убрать из L рандомно выбранные элементы и добавить их в первый список нового списка и так далее, но пока с синтаксисом не разобралась, как это сделать
Нужно использвать random.sample , цикл, генератор

```
  import random
    #random.sample?
    n = 7
    m = 3
    L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    L2 = L.copy()
    li = []
    k = 0
    count = 0
    while n>0:
        for i in L:
            while count < m:
                random.sample(L, n)
                li[k].append(i)
                L.remove(i)
                count += 1
                n -=1
```

Comment: Выложите пример вашего кода с описанием конкретной проблемы.

Comment: Простите, что задаю вопрос, но что такое батчи? Даже погуглив, плохо понимаю о чём речь. К тому же совсем не понятно, какой вид у входных и выходных данных. Слишком много неопределённости (лично для меня).

Comment: Батчи - блоки, например: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` делим на два равных блока: `[1, 2]` `[3, 4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вариант "в лоб":

```
import random
n = 7
m = 3
L = list(range(1, n+1))
batchs = []
while len(L):
    if len(L) >= m:
        b = random.sample(L, m)

        for i in range(len(L)-1, -1, -1):
            if L[i] in b:
                L.pop(i)
    else:
        b = L
        L = []
    batchs.append(b)

print(batchs)
```

Но можно сделать хитрее. Выбирать с помощью `random.sample` не значения, а индексы списка.

Comment: Как завернуть код в генератор (yield)?

Comment: В соответствии с документацией. Можно здесь почитать: http://zetblog.ru/python-obyasnenie-raboty-yield-iteratorov-i-generatorov.html Если не получится, выложишь код, опишешь проблему, поможем.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку